# Flutter builded App bundle not working Correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play-console

I've tested my flutter app in  debug mode its working perfectly in debug mode.So I changed the test ad id to real ad id and created app bundle and uploaded it the playstore. When I downloaded the app via playstore it's not working correctly.I've tried `flutter clean` and build again and uploaded it again. But issue is still remaining.I've also tried split apks. What should I do?

Update :
There is function in my app which is let user to load image from thier storage to app.It is not working in release version but it's working perfectly in debug mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working correctly."

Comment: Functions of the app not working..It's not  even loading image from gallery when I tried select image from gallery.It worked fine when tried it using debug mode.

Comment: You specifically state the features that aren't working in your question.